# Node module to build tree like structure in angular 2, 4

Tags: angular, npm

Is there any node package to build tree like structure in angular 2, 4 similar to this https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example

where I can customize the templates

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to go with [Primeng Tree](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree) Component. They have really good community support and many functions comes out of the box.

Another option is to go with [Ng2-Tree](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree). It also has many great features built in. But personally I prefer to go with primeng